# Why does the number of constructor calls not match with the number of destructor calls?

Tags: c++

I am very confused about the following piece of code.

```
#include <iostream>

class mobject
{
public:
    mobject(){ std::cout << "mobject ctor\n"; }
    ~mobject(){ std::cout << "mobject dtor\n"; }
};

mobject giveme() { return mobject(); }
void func2(const mobject& p) { mobject g = p; }
void func1(const mobject& p) { func2(p); }
int main()
{
    func1(giveme());
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the following output:

```
mobject ctor
mobject dtor
mobject dtor
```

I compiled the code with gcc 5.4.0 with `"g++ -g temp.cpp". My main concern is the second call tor mobjects's destructor. That looks to be quite wrong since we call dtor a second time. valgrind tells me there is no problem with this one but still I am confused.

Comment: You constructed 2 objects, a temporary and a named local object `g`. Then there're two destructors being invoked.

Comment: Did you hear about copy constructor, which has signature `mobject(const myobject&)`, you made a copy object, hence 2 destructors were called.

Answer (score 10):

Your code constructs two `mobjects`, one default constructed and the other copy constructed, but you have only put a print message in the default constructor and ignored the copy constructor. Note also that your function calls are irrelevant to the problem at hand:

```
#include <iostream>

struct mobject
{
    mobject(const mobject& /* other */){ std::cout << "mobject copy-ctor\n"; }
    mobject(){ std::cout << "mobject ctor\n"; }
    ~mobject(){ std::cout << "mobject dtor\n"; }
};

int main()
{
  const mobject& p = mobject();
  mobject g = p;
}
```

which gives:

```
mobject ctor
mobject copy-ctor
mobject dtor
mobject dtor
```

Answer (score 1):

Two lines of output of `mobject dtor` is due to following:

- First object is created when you calls `giveme()` function in `main` in line `func1(giveme());`. This gives the 3rd line of output `mobject dtor`, when program ends.
- 2nd object is created using `default-copy-constructor` in line `mobject g = p;` of function `func2`. 2nd line of output `mobject dtor` is when this object is getting deleted in return from this function.

Following modified code and respective output will demonstrate it:

```
class mobject
{
public:
    mobject(const mobject& ob){ cout << "mobject overridden-copy-constructor\n"; }
    mobject(){ cout << "mobject ctor\n"; }
    ~mobject(){ cout << "mobject dtor\n"; }
};

mobject giveme() 
{ 
    cout << "1. In Function: "<<__func__<<endl;
    return mobject(); 
}
void func2(const mobject& p) 
{ 
    cout << "2. In Function: "<<__func__<<endl;
    mobject g = p; 
    cout << "3. In Function: "<<__func__<<endl;
}
void func1(const mobject& p) 
{ 
    cout << "4. In Function: "<<__func__<<endl;
    func2(p); 
    cout << "5. In Function: "<<__func__<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "6. In Function: "<<__func__<<endl;
    func1(giveme());
    cout << "7. In Function: "<<__func__<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
6. In Function: main
1. In Function: giveme
mobject ctor
4. In Function: func1
2. In Function: func2
mobject overridden-copy-constructor
3. In Function: func2
mobject dtor
5. In Function: func1
mobject dtor
7. In Function: main
```

See [here](https://ideone.com/TKeIe9) working code it.

Comment: If you are using `std::endl`, you will flush the stream and you make it more difficult for the stream to buffer the output. This is not wrong per se, it is just something one should be aware of.